# Unix Script: Wait until a file exists

Tags: unix, shell-script

I need a script that will wait for a (examplefile.txt) to appear in the /tmp directory

and once it's found to stop the program, otherwise to sleep the file until it's located

So far I have:

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/examplefile.txt ]

then
```

Answer (score 55):

```sh
until [ -f /tmp/examplefile.txt ]
do
     sleep 5
done
echo "File found"
exit
```

**Info**: Use `-d` instead of `-f` to check for directories, or `-e` to check for files or directories.

Every 5 seconds it will wake up and look for the file.  When the file appears, it will drop out of the loop, tell you it found the file and exit (not required, but tidy.)

Put that into a script and start it as
script &

That will run it in the background.

There may be subtle differences in syntax depending on the shell you use.  But that is the gist of it.

Comment: using sleeps might be inevitable, but this would be the most robust with an API that wait()s for an acknowledgement. but that would also have to have control of the writing-application too.

Answer (score 30):

Try this shell function:

```
# Block until the given file appears or the given timeout is reached.
# Exit status is 0 iff the file exists.
wait_file() {
  local file="$1"; shift
  local wait_seconds="${1:-10}"; shift # 10 seconds as default timeout
  test $wait_seconds -lt 1 && echo 'At least 1 second is required' && return 1

  until test $((wait_seconds--)) -eq 0 -o -e "$file" ; do sleep 1; done

  test $wait_seconds -ge 0 # equivalent: let ++wait_seconds
}
```

And here's how you can use it:

```
# Wait at most 5 seconds for the server.log file to appear

server_log=/var/log/jboss/server.log

wait_file "$server_log" 5 || {
  echo "JBoss log file missing after waiting for 5 seconds: '$server_log'"
  exit 1
}
```

Another example:

```
# Use the default timeout of 10 seconds:
wait_file "/tmp/examplefile.txt" && {
  echo "File found."
}
```

Comment: A more precise way to calculate a timeout would probably be: `start=\`date +%s\`; while (( \`date +%s\` - start > 10 )); do sleep 1; done`

Comment: This is super cool but I just want to comment that `-f` is only for _regular_ files. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) for file conditional expressions in bash if you need to wait for some other kind of file.

Comment: It seems that the exit code can be only 0 (file found) or 1 (not found), instead of how many secs the function has waited.

Comment: `((++wait_seconds))` is not POSIX, I used instead `let ++wait_seconds` on another shell.

Comment: @Phil Thanks! I've updated the function.